# Change page.tpl template inside a hook_menu callback

Tags: 6, theming, routes

I have a hook_menu like that:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['mymodule-test'] = array(
        'page callback' => '_mymodule_test_callback',
        'access callback' => TRUE
    );
    return $items;
}
```

and the callback function:

```
function _mymodule_test_callback()
{
    // processing
    return $html;
}
```

I googled around but i cant find how to force the page template inside my _mymodule_test_callback function.

**Edit: why i cant (or dont feel comfortable with) url-based suggestion**

Url-based suggestion are easy to implement, however they can not completely fit my needs.

The template I have to use is determined in the _mymodule_test_callback function, according to very various aspects, for example:

1. Does exists a node of type 'foo', and does the field 'abc' value's be 'xyx'? => choose template 'page-mymodule-foo.tpl.php'
2. The node does exists, but the field 'abc' value is empty? => Choose temlate 'page-mymodule-bar.tpl.php'
3. The node does not exist at all, but the user has the 'bimbumbam' role? => Choose template 'page-mymodule-foobarz.tpl.php'

...and so on.

I know this is a rare behavior, and that i could redirect instead of switching template, but actually the function body is not big and i prefer to do this way.

Is not possible?

Comment: if my understanding of you query "to use a custom page template other than page.tpl.php for this specific menu callback" is right, you could use page-internal_path.tpl.php which in this case should be `page-mymodule-test.tpl.php` based on my understanding of [Drupal 6 template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089642), please let me know if i've misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Silly me, off course using page-<path>.tpl.php is the best answer when the custom page template is needed for a single page callback.

Comment: @PierreBuyle You're right, but the problem comes when i have to choose the template file according to what happen in the _mymodule_test_callback() function.
For example, if a determinate node exist and has some attributes, i can choose 'foo' template, else, 'bar' template.
If the node doesnt exist at all and the user have the 'cippalippa' role, then i have to choose the 'foobar' template.. and so on ;)

Comment: @optimusprime619 You understood right my question, but my question lack of details.. my bad, i update the question ;)

Comment: have you checked the possibilities of enforcing such conditions in your `module_preprocess_page()` with `&$variables` like mentioned in below answer? In similar situations I've done such stuff in my `theme_preprocess_page()` with function calls to modules to determine decision making conditions, one bad experience with White screen of death when calling function of module which is disabled made me use `function_exists` and `module_exists` before calling a function to be on safer side, but it goes without saying that though my approach worked for me its muddy and not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly change the page template from a page callback. You can either bypass the full page rendering by printing your page content from your page callback. Or you can use a global variable to trigger addition of template suggestion in [`hook_preprocess_HOOK`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/6) implementation.

```
function _no_template_page_callback() {
  // ... processing ...
  // Print the result, and bypass the page template (so no blocks, no CSS, no JavaScript, etc.). 
  print $html;
}

function _template_suggestions_callback() {
  global $MODULE_page_template_suggestions;  
  // ... processing ...
  // Set flag to trigger usage of our custom page template. 
  $MODULE_suggest_page_template = $suggestions;
  return $html;
}

function MODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $MODULE_page_template_suggestions;
  if (!empty($MODULE_page_template_suggestions)) {
    // Use template suggestions set from _template_suggestions_callback the module.
    foreach ($MODULE_page_template_suggestions as $suggestion) {
      $variables['template_files'][] = $suggestion;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: nice one, have a doubt on the precedence...will the template suggestion in `modulename_preprocess_page` be overidden if there's a similar condition for the OP's template suggestion also exists in `theme_preprocess_page` ?